# Using "the" with past participle but not with the present participle

Tags: grammaticality, semantics

I am currently working on a book review of verb presentation in two texts. I am contemplating the nominal function of present participles. Of course, we know that a present participle is called a gerund or is functioning nominally. However, it is odd to say "The swimming is fun," but we can say "Swimming is fun." For the past participle counterpart, we find instances like "The dead." Consider the following sentences: "The damned are in hell." "Doctor Faustus is among the wretched." "They buried the dead." The past participle, affixed with "the" before it, functions nominally- in the place of the subject, direct object, and the object of the preposition.

So, why can we say "the dead" but not "the flying?"

Comment: That particular article usage converts an adjective (often one formed from a participle, like _dying_ or _wounded_) into a noun phrase signifying people or things the adjective modifies: _Separate the living from the dead_ means to separate living people from dead ones. The distinction between present participle forms with _-ing_ and past participle forms with _-ed_ or _-en_ is just a matter of how many adjectives get formed from each. Perfect participles are much more common as adjectives, because predicate adjectives in _-ing_ are identical with the progressive construction.

Comment: You can say "the flying", meaning either things which fly, or to refer to a particular act of flight ("the flying of a bee"); although neither is very common.

Answer (score 0):

The present and past participles are often written identically to related adjectives.

When we say “the damned”, “the wretched”, “the dead” or “the dying”, those are adjectives with an implied noun of “people”, so an article makes sense. “The flying” sounds weird because it’s hard to imagine a context where “the flying (people)” makes sense.

Gerunds are not adjectives; they are nouns that (usually) do not take an article. In fact, this lack of article is a clue to distinguish them from the adjective.

- The dying (people) are in pain.
- Dying is painful.